# ORA-01427: SELECT * FROM TABLE gives error single-row subquery returns more than one row

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, cx-oracle

I tried using the following variants:

```
SELECT * FROM "DB"."TABLE"
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM "DB"."TABLE"
SELECT reference FROM "DB"."TABLE"
SELECT reference FROM "DB"."TABLE" WHERE rownum < 2
```

where reference was a specific field of type *cx_Oracle.STRING*

All of those return the following error:

```
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
```

I don't see why the final example would return an error complaining about returning more than one row, nor why returning more than one row would be a problem here in any of the examples.

I've seen a lot of similar problems on SO, but they all have nested selects where I can understand this being problematic, but these should just be simple selects.

The database is Oracle 11g Enterprise Edition, and it is being accessed through the cx_Oracle python interface.

Comment: is it a table? maybe you select from a view.

Comment: ibre is probably right. You must select from a view.

Comment: Ok that would make sense with the sub query, but why would that cause SELECT * FROM "DB"."TABLE" to fail?

Comment: You need to show the whole query.

Comment: @GeorgeBroughton - because the query the view is defined with is itself doing a subquery. You can look at the `text` column in `all_views` to see what it is actually doing (assuming it is a view, which seems to be the case). When you query the view its underlying query is being executed, and that is hitting the error because of the view's subquery. Your `count(1)` should work though, I think...

Comment: I think you will have to post more code, enough for us to understand the context, if you hope to get a more helpful response.

Comment: Ok yes it appears to be part of a problem with the view itself. It's on a 3rd party system so I won't post it here but they're looking into it now. Thanks for the help guys

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the 'table' I was pulling from was in fact a database view, a sort of pseudo-table, which is composed of sql joining together other tables.

The error actually lay in the view, rather than in my SQL, which is where the subquery referred to in the error was. Thanks for the help in the comments!